# Silex/Symfony Security: How to perform additional checks for user login?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, firewall, silex

Im working with Silex Security, the firewalls and security stuff is configured this way:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/secured/',
            'form' => array(
                'login_path' => '/login',
                'check_path' => '/secured/login_check'
            ),
            'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
                return new CustomUserProvider($app["db"]);
            }),
            'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/secured/logout'),
            'switch_user' => array('parameter' => '_cambiar_usuario', 'role' => 'ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH')
        )
    )
));
```

All works fine, but now I want to perform additional checks to the user, in this case I want to check if user email was validated (it is just check if a database field is true or false) admore to the user - password check. if mail validation is not done yet I want to make auth fail with a custom message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it myself. I had to extend Symfony's `UserChecker` class and overrode `checkPreAuth` method to add my extra check.

After that I replaced the default user checker by mine:

```
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
         //my firewalls
    )
));

$app['security.user_checker'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new CustomUserChecker();
});
```